# Apache to Ngnix Rewrite to a Directory confusion

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, rewrite

i could use a little help with rewrite and nginx...
Basically the structure of my App looks like this

```
Headdirectory --
           -APPBase
           -SomeMoreStuff
           -WWWDirectory
           .htaccess
```

So i need to redirect into the WWWDirectory when i open the Headdirectory.
In Apache its done with a htaccess and the following Content :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) www/$1
```

I already tried in Nginx :

```
location /Headdirectory {    
rewrite ^/(.*) /www/$1;
      }
```

And i tried to create an Alias but that didnt work...

Would be nice if someone could help me out.

Have a nice Day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how it could be done in Nginx...

```
server {
  server_name domain.com;
  root /path/to/domain.com;
  index index.php; # or index.html or something that suits the application

  location ~ /Headdirectory/WWWDirectory/ {
    # do some stuff with WWWDirectory
    # something like try_files $uri =404;
  }

  location ~ /Headdirectory/ {
    rewrite ^/Headdirectory/(.*)$ /Headdirectory/WWWDirectory/$1 permanent;
  }

  # other blocks and directives

  location / {
    # do stuff with the root
    # such as try_files $uri =404;
  }
}
```

Questions?

Comment: That worked , Thank you very much. I'm still pretty new to this regular expression stuff :)

Answer (score 1):

It is a little bit confusing question...

Your configuration is, that if someone will try `http://some.host/Headdirectory`, it will be rewriten to `http://some.host/www/Headdirectory`, which is not you want, I pretend...

Try this:

```
root /full/path/to/the/Headdirectory
location / {
     rewrite ^/(.*) /www/$1;
}
```

EDIT:

I'm sorry, you will need this config block:

```
location /www {
}
```

It will stop rewriting...

Comment: Thank you in Advance. Sorry , its a bit early for me. I need to open the Headdirectory , because my App requires it, but the redirect needs to go to the www directory. When i try this i get in a redirect loop. www/www/www/www/www/www 
Basically if someone goes to the

Comment: Please, try add a new block to the config...

Comment: Sorry, this block existed with the old path ..^^
Now Firefox and Chrome say that there are too many redirects. Errorlog is empty. Thanks , i only want to migrate to nginx :/